Were there slaves who opposed abolition?
Is there any record of slaves who opposed abolition?
I’m especially interested in evidence of internalized oppression and of slaves who believed it would be unfair to them if the next generation got to be free.

Various Google searches only return already-popular abolitionists and their (white) opponents. 2) Evidence need not have been created by slaves themselves: maybe a slaveholder wrote in his diary in 1865 that his slaves wished to remain with him.


What have you searched/looked for so far? Any book? Reference? Hints?

Slaves weren't usually allowed to learn to read and write. Those who did so secretly, and escaped, were perforce not proslavery. Imho anyone who learnt to write and wrote with the blessing of slavemasters would either be coerced or brainwashed.

an authoritative answer would require proof of absence of evidence - proving a negative. Recommend question closure. I'm not sure how to revise this question into one that is appropriate to the SE

This is not really going to be possible to objectively talk about, for the simple reason that enslaved people were not free to express transgressive opinions. By definition.
It would not be possible to tell the difference between an honestly held opinion in favor of their condition and one arrived at under coercion, from someone who was currently living their life under coercion. This is roughly in the same category as statutory rape, where the victim's entirely uncoerced and informed opinion on the matter is kind of unknowable, so we consider it completely beside the point. The person with power was taking advantage of the person without power. End of story.
What we can talk about is the enslaved collaborating with their enslavers. That definitely happened. However, given that slavemasters were known to punish those left behind when an enslaved person successfully escaped (and mass hangings with little regard to guilt in the case of violence against the enslavers), that was likely as not a matter of self-preservation, not sympathy with the system.

There is a window of opportunity after the war when all slaves, regardless of their honest opinion of their previous station, were freed.  Since they are unlikely to be literate, their opinions might have been recorded by others. (e.g. family, neighbors).  I know of no such reports but I can imagine a descendant reporting that grandpa rued his freedom because life was simpler on the plantation - blocking out memories of the bad things, much like folks harken back to the days of the USSR in modern Russian.  Without an example, it is just a hypothesis though.

@vsfDawg - I thought about that. The problem is their opinions on the matter, even in retrospect, would have been shaded by the fact that it was very much in their own best interest to mirror the opinions of their enslavers on the matter. Even after the coercion ends, people have an incentive to justify their past behavior, even if those justifications weren't the reason for it. There were also quite possibly some formerly enslaved people who, after manumission, had some surprising views on which condition ended up being better, but that wasn't the question that was asked.

@vsfDawg - Also, you should realize that a lot of formerly enslaved people after manumission ended up being sharecroppers on the land of the same families that had enslaved them, which is still a position of coercion. We do actually have some recorded interviews with former slaves still living in The South before they died due to the WPA, but one of the problems that's been pointed out with those is that they tended to hire white locals (particularly plantation owners) to carry out the interviews, and that has somewhat tainted the honestly of the replies on some subjects.

Do you think there were any freed slaves who opposed abolition after the civil war?
